# How to run powershell command using groovy in soapui?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I wanted to run the below powershell command as a administrator in the groovy..

```
PS C:\Program Files\APP\Bin> .\app.AdminTool.ps1 -url "https://reference1.jdm-inc.com" enqueue orchestration -file  "C:\Program Files\APP\Importer\daily_report.xml"  -properties @{ 'processing_date' = '2017-01-17' }
```

I have used following code to run this.

```
String workingDir= System.setProperty("user.dir","C:\\Program Files\\APP\\Bin")
log.info(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
```

I kept the below command in the one variable.

```
.\app.AdminTool.ps1 -url "https://reference1.jdm-inc.com" enqueue orchestration -file  "C:\Program Files\APP\Importer\daily_report.xml"  -properties @{ 'processing_date' = '2017-01-17' }
```

I have tried the below command to change the path and

```
def proc = "cmd /C dir".execute().text
return proc
```

This brings always soapui bin folder path.. How to change the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def powerShellCommand = '.\\app.AdminTool.ps1 -url "https://reference1.jdm-inc.com" enqueue orchestration -file  "C:\\Program Files\\APP\\Importer\\daily_report.xml"  -properties @{ \'processing_date\' = \'2017-01-17\' }'
def shellCommand = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile  -Command \"${powerShellCommand}\""
def process = shellCommand.execute()
process.waitFor()
```

Then you have access to the Process.outputStream to read the command output.

Comment: app.AdminTool.ps1 is in C:\Program Files\APP\Bin.. without going in to that directory.. will it work?

Comment: You can just give full path to the script. Don't forget to escape any backslashes since it's windows paths.

Comment: def powerShellCommand = C:\\Program Files\\APP\\Bin\\app.AdminTool.ps1 -url "https://reference1.jdm-inc.com" enqueue orchestration -file  "C:\\Program Files\\APP\\Importer\\daily_report.xml"  -properties @{ \'processing_date\' = \'2017-01-17\' }'  is this the approach you are saying?

Comment: Yes, why don't you just try it with a simple command first. Then you can expand to your command.

Comment: This is one of my requirment to pull the report in soapui.. I am not much familiar on powershell command.. i am just to run this command to execute from soap ui that this is creating report or not in the DB.

Comment: seems it is not working.. i am trying to get the text output of the script. it is coming empty

Comment: How to change directory to C:\Program Files\APP\Bin before executing the script? If i give full path, it is not working

Comment: You can call `.execute(null, new File("your working dir")` to change the working directory and run the command there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139993/discussion-between-changan-and-strelok).

Comment: tried this.. execute(process , new File("C:\\Program Files\\APP\\Bin") . It is not working..

Comment: I have placed file in C:\ and your solution works for me